# Trying to setup dual boot. Now nothing boots :/

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have been trying to setup dual bot in my laptop (ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1) and right now the computer doesn't boot and I get the error: "Insert system disk in drive. Press any key when ready." Last thing I did before this was using boot-repair, here is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12875802/

I have followed probably to many tutorial and I think I mixed up things a bit. I want to ask here before trying to start from wero again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the OS has corrupted to some level, not sure where. You should first install Windows and then install Ubuntu (prefer Live USB Because of higher speed) and choose dual booting (side by side).

In my case, I couldn't boot my Ubuntu but could boot my Windows PC, so I basically go in Advanced Options and boot using `systemfs` or something of that sort.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I got this laptop with Windows preinstalled so I can't install Windows.

Comment: Who said you can't

Comment: I meant I don't have any Windows disk.

Comment: Well, you can download an ISO and burn it on a DVD (Windows 10's Free! - At the cost of your private data!) or just contact your company

Answer (score 0):

It seems something has corrupted the boot functionality.
You can completely rebuild the whole boot environment.

First try to change the boot order in BIOS (UEFI) settings.
Select Windows as the default operating system to boot.

If Windows does not start, boot from the **Windows installation media**.
When the "**Install now**" screen appears select "**Repair your computer**".

Choose "**Troubleshoot**" then open "**Command prompt**" and execute :

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Now reboot into Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.
To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

Then reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note :

`sda` = disk | `sda2` = efi partition | `sda7` = system partition
(taken from the pastebin output referred in your question)

To re-check the partition numbers use **GParted**.
The tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.

Boot into BIOS and change the boot order in UEFI settings.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

You can select which OS to boot from the GRUB boot menu.
As always I strongly recommend to **not** use 3rd party tools !

Note : If you don't have a Windows installation media, you can download the Windows Enterprise Edition ISO from Microsoft TechNet Evaluation Center and create the DVD or USB media from it !